# Input not updated accordingly when element values are changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a form where the user will be charged an additional fee of $5if one of the following option is true :

Inscription field is not empty | contains text

OR

radio button 'Decoration petites fleurs souhaitee'

OR

radio button 'Decoration chocolat et fruits souhaitee'

As you can see in the following video my script is reacting strangely and is not consequently applying the additional fee to the total price :

[click here](https://www.screencast.com/t/VhmfsccU)

Prix (Price) + Supplement (additional fee or surcharge) = Total (Total price)

I can't figure out why. Would need your expertise here. Thanks in advance.

Here is a link to the form code :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3duf4oe2qerr1rt/FORMCODE.txt?dl=0

Here is my script (js file) :

```
$(window).bind('change', function() {

    /* Inscription */
    var textmessage = $('#desserttextmessage').val();
    /* Prix */
    var productprice = parseFloat($('#productprice').val());
    /* Supplément */
    var surcharge = 5.00;
    var nosurcharge = 0.00;
    var totalsurcharge = parseFloat(surcharge);
    var productaddfee = parseFloat($('#productaddfee').val());
    var total = parseFloat(productprice).toFixed(2);
    var totalfee = parseFloat(productprice + productaddfee).toFixed(2);
    /* Decoration */
    var valuedecorflower = $('input[name=dessertdecorflowerID]:checked').val();
    var valuedecorchocolate = $('input[name=dessertdecorchocolateID]:checked').val();

        if (textmessage != '' || valuedecorchocolate == 'Décoration chocolat et fruits souhaitée' || valuedecorflower == 'Décoration petites fleurs souhaitée') {

            $('#productaddfee').val(parseFloat(totalsurcharge).toFixed(2));
            $('#total').val(parseFloat(totalfee).toFixed(2));

        } else if (textmessage == '' && valuedecorchocolate == 'Pas de décoration chocolat et fruits' && valuedecorflower == 'Pas de décoration petites fleurs') {

            $('#productaddfee').val(parseFloat(nosurcharge).toFixed(2));
            $('#total').val(parseFloat(total).toFixed(2));

        }

})
```

Comment: We're going to need to see your HTML. At a guess, I suspect the element you want to put the total into doesn't actually have the `id` attribute set to `total` as you imply in your javascript or `total` isn't a unique id.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, id is set to total :

<input type="number" step="1" title="Total" disabled="" class="form-control" name="total" id="total" value="0"> and is a unique id into the form

Comment: thanks for the compliment ;-) I'm learning coding. I'm developing with Laravel and I'm using a dashboard extension called 'Crudbooster' which is generating cruds to custome. I will make a copy outerHML and past it into my original post, sorry for the code which will be a mess too.

Comment: link to form code can be found into the original post|question

Comment: In the HTML you provided, there are two instances of `id="total"`.

Comment: <input type="number" step="1" title="Total" disabled="" class="form-control" name="total" id="total" value="0"> at the top of the formcode document is just a copy of the input with the 'total' id I mistakenly forgot to erase. So only one id "total' in the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is this line:

```
var productaddfee = parseFloat($('#productaddfee').val());
```

Basically, you're using an old, possibly invalid, value to compute new values in some cases.

After cleanup, it should look something like this:

```
$(window).bind('change', function() {
    // Get the form values we need to work with
    /* Inscription */
    var textmessage = $('#desserttextmessage').val();
    /* Prix */
    var productprice = parseFloat($('#productprice').val());
    /* Decoration */
    var valuedecorflower = $('input[name=dessertdecorflowerID]:checked').val();
    var valuedecorchocolate = $('input[name=dessertdecorchocolateID]:checked').val();

    // compute the surcharge
    var surcharge = 0.00;
    if (textmessage != '' || valuedecorchocolate != 'Pas de décoration chocolat et fruits' || valuedecorflower != 'Pas de décoration petites fleurs') {
        surcharge = 5.00;
    }

    // compute the total
    var total = productprice + surcharge;

    // set the results
    $('#productaddfee').val(surcharge.toFixed(2));
    $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

Note: In a learning environment, things are mostly fine. In a production environment, your code suffers from vulnerabilities allowing a knowledgeable user to set whatever price they wish.

Comment: Well noted @Ouroborus, will not go into production without a vulnerability check by a senior dev. 
Thanks for your expertise, it is working as expected, a good lesson to learn to code slim, cheers